# PostgreSQL: convert function's parameter to seconds

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I've created a function that must convert it's parameter to seconds:

```
CREATE TYPE DiffTimeKoverAndAllInProgressType AS (f2 double precision); 
create function ExtractSeconds(interval) returns setof DiffTimeKoverAndAllInProgressType as

'SELECT extract(epoch from interval $$00:10:00$$);' language 'sql';
```

Result:

```
$ psql -d test1 -c "select * from  ExtractSeconds('00:10:00');"
 f2  
-----
 600
(1 row)
```

But if I want to use a parameter instead of hard-coded const value:

```
create function ExtractSeconds(interval) returns setof DiffTimeKoverAndAllInProgressType as

        'SELECT extract(epoch from interval $$$1$$);' language 'sql';
```

Result:

```
$psql -d test1 -c "select * from  ExtractSeconds('00:10:00');"
  f2 
 ----
   1
(1 row)
```

QUESTION: What should I do in order to get normal value (e.g. '600') and to pass a parameter without const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input parameter is already an interval, I don't think you need to do anything, including the casting -- I believe you can take the parameter as-is:

```
create or replace function ExtractSeconds(interval)
returns setof DiffTimeKoverAndAllInProgressType as
$BODY$
  SELECT extract(epoch from $1);
$BODY$
language 'sql';
```

Outputs:

```
select * from  ExtractSeconds('00:10:00');   -- return 600

select * from  ExtractSeconds('00:15:00');   -- return 900

select * from  ExtractSeconds('1 week 4 days 2 hours');  -- returns 957600
```